# Continuity of $f$ implies continuity of $f(-\log x)$

Tags: calculus, continuity

If a function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$, is it true that $f(- \log x)$ is continuous on $(0, 1]$?

If yes, then how would I prove it?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Yes that is true, in general the composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Dear Cohen, its true that the composition of function is continuous, but in this particular case, as the lower limit value of interval (0, 1] is 0 and - log x would be evaluated on it. i .e., log 0 which is indeterminate. So how would I manipulate it.

Comment: I actually want to prove it using the epsilon-delta definition of continuity.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct: although $\log 0$ is indeterminate, we do not need it to prove continuity. For continuity of $f(- \log x)$ it suffices to prove continuity at every value in the interval $(0, 1]$.

Continuity atna value is a local condition, which means that to prove continuity at a value we only have to consider a very small interval around it. For example, we can show that $f(- \log x)$ is continuous at every value $\epsilon$ in the interval $(0,1]$ by only considering the interval $(1/2 \epsilon, 1]$. Perhaps this helps you realize that $x=0$ plays no role in this story?

Answer (score 0):

You even don't have to consider continuity in particular values. Consider the following functions:

- $\log: (0, 1] \to (-∞, 0]$,

  $(-): (-∞, 0] \to [0, ∞)$,

  $f: [0, ∞) \to ℂ$.

All of them are continuous, and your function $x \mapsto f(-\log x)$ defined on $(0, 1]$ is their composition, and hence continuous.